# Copying Files from Failing Drive

Tags: data-recovery

I have a failing hard drive that I'm trying to copy the files off of, but it randomly hangs on damaged files and I/O errors. If I ctrl+c I can start back up. I need to preserve the file structure, so I don't want to dump all the files into a single archive, like gddrescue or get a dump of every file in a drive, like foremost. Can anyone recommend a program that will give a timeout and continue to the next file?

Using rsync will begin to copy files, but rsync will get stuck, when it has an I/O error or comes across a corrupt file. This is the command I tried:

sudo rsync --progress --ignore-errors -avh source dest

Comment: Your comment about ddrescue does not make sense. It does preserve everything and that's precisely what a professional recovery service would do in your case.

Comment: I'm not trying to recover everything, just specific files, before the drive fails, completely.

Comment: It doesn't matter. That's how professional file recovery is done. First you clone the drive, then you work on the copy and extract what you need. It could be a single file as well. That's the standard procedure.

Comment: If I want to copy 50 files off a drive, it doesn't make sense to image the entire drive, when the other 120k files, plus all the empty space is worthless.

Answer (score 5):

Correct way is to run [ddrescue](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ddrescue.1.html):

- If you have new empty drive with size greater or equal to failing one:

  ```
  sudo ddrescue /dev/sd_source /dev/sd_backup ~/log_file --try-again --force --verbose
  ```
- If you have mounted partition of new drive with enough disk space:

  ```
  sudo ddrescue /dev/sd_source /media/user/backup/backup.raw ~/log_file --try-again --force --verbose
  ```

And then you can work with copy in any way (for example mount it and save data). Do not touch original (failing) disk anymore before you are completely assured that copy works normally.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the files hangs likely due to corrupted data.  If you have a spare hard drive of sufficient capacity, you could use gddrescue to clone the bad HDD to the good HDD *instead* of an image, and generate a log file as well.  That should buy you some time to work on recovering the data without the impending peril of the HDD failure.  [This](https://datarecovery.com/rd/how-to-clone-hard-disks-with-ddrescue/) article should be useful as it shows how to invoke either cloning to a hdd or image file.

**Edit** I interpret `single archive` as meaning an image file

Comment: +1; [This link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986) may help too. Scroll down to 'Advanced repair of a partition table, file system and/or recovery of files'

Answer (score 0):

1 word:  `rsync`

rsync is very capable of copying files in one direction, and you can restart it if the process crashes.  Additionally, you can use the `--ignore-errors` flag to force it to keep going even when an error happens, and if you need to restart it, it will skip trying to copy files it already copied.

Comment: it's not that complicated:  `rsync -axHAWXS --numeric-ids --ignore-errors --info=progress2 /from/src/drive /to/dest/drive`

Comment: You might also want the `--partial` instead of the `-W` flag which will keep partially transfered files.  Be warned, that these will likely be corrupt.

Comment: I tried both of these options. Neither one worked. Rsync would start to copy, get to a corrupted file and hang.

Comment: It's going to hang... there's no way around it.  The hang is caused by read errors on the disk, and the OS waits for the disk to report back an error which is what causes the hang.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use something like `ddrescue` to dump a disk-image to a file, then mount it as a loopback device to recover whatever you're looking for.  It is unlikely you will recover a functioning system from a corrupted drive.

Comment: My goal is not to recover a functional system, but to get files out of a user profile, , while keeping the file structure, with minimal interaction. GNU ddrescue will work, but it seems like overkill to rescue an entire 1tb  drive, just to get 30gb of files.

Comment: @talkinggoat You really only have 3 options.  Wait out the disk-read timeouts using a cp or rsync... clone the disk, to a working disk (or file) then copy whatever you need that isn't corrupted... or rely on fsck to mark  & attempt-recovery of the errors on the disk, and likely destroy the file-system in the process.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1021974/edit) your answer with full command.

Comment: @TheCompWiz There's no way to tell the OS to reduce the read timeout so it doesn't hang? I'm currently encountering this, and the read hangs indefinitely at a single read. There doesn't appear to be any timeout. I agree that using ddrescure would be an option, but setting up a desktop to do that is a huge hassle, especially just to recover a small amount of data from a 1TB drive.

Comment: I did not have a suitable target for ddrescue, and `rscync -arvm \failingDrive\dir\ \goodDrive\dir` saved me.   (where `a` means keep the original permissions, `r` means recursive, `v` means verbose and `m` means prune empty directory chains)